# JAVA: Can't compile files in same package with Javac

Tags: java, compilation, package

I did search for quite a bit, but still cannot solve the wonderful problem of JAVA: packages.
I have 2 small classes, in the same package: elte.esti.beadando
The 2 files are called NimJatek and NimMain.
when I compile NimJatek with the following:
    `c:\elte\esti\beadando\javac NimJatek.java`
it complies no problem then when I try to compile:
    `c:\elte\esti\beadando\javac NimMain.java`
It gives an error:NimJatek symbol not found.

I've tried every possible combination, but it still doesn't work.
The combinations I've tried so far:

```
c:\elte\esti\beadando\javac -cp c:\elte\esti\beadando NimMain.java
c:\elte\esti\beadando\javac -cp c:\elte\esti\beadando beadando/NimMain.java
c:\elte\esti\beadando\javac -cp c:\elte\esti\beadando.NimJatek NimMain.java
c:\elte\esti\beadando\javac -cp c:\elte\esti\beadando.NimJatek beadando/NimMain.java
c:\elte\esti\beadando\javac -cp c:\elte\esti\beadando.NimJatek.class NimMain.java
c:\elte\esti\javac beadando/NimMain.java
c:\elte\esti\javac -cp c:\elte\esti\beadando.NimJatek beadando/NimMain.java
c:\elte\esti\javac -cp c:\elte\esti\beadando.NimJatek.class beadando/NimMain.java
c:\javac -cp c:\elte\esti\beadando.NimJatek elte\esti\beadando/NimMain.java
```

And probably some more, I can't recall. What am I missing?? When I remove the "package elte.esti.beadando" from both files they compile and run beautifully.

NOTE: I don't want to use a complier program, I can only use command line (windows).

Comment: Are you sure your java files have a `package` statement at the top (that is, `package elte.esti.badando` and only then imports and class?

Comment: Yes, I'm positive. I know that in case of packages, the "package xy" statement comes first that's correct.

Comment: dbrown93 - I tried that as well. Please take a look in my original post, the variations I've tried so far.

Comment: path = parent directory not a file.

Answer (score 2):

Since there are multiple files, I believe that running

```
javac c:\elte\esti\beadando\*.java
```

should compile correctly assuming that the dependencies are limited to the package itself.

Answer (score 0):

> package elte.esti.beadando

This means the Java files must appear under the `elte/esti/beadando` directory under your class path. If the file is in

> C:\elte\esti\beadando\NimJatek.java

This means the root directory of your package is `c:\`

This means you would have to use

```
javac -cp C:\ C:\elte\esti\beadando\NimMain.java
```

Instead of trying to setup a project from scratch, you will save yourself a lot of trail and error by using an IDE which will setup the project, edit it, check it before you compile it and compile/run it in one button.

Comment: We have to do it this way... but it still does not work :( Tried to compile from root directory, also as you suggested, but it still doesn't work. If I remove the "package elte.esti.beadando" from both files, and then compile, it works...

Comment: Does it run successfully after compilation?

Comment: @user3420063 what do you mean by "it doesn't work" What does it do?

Comment: @user3420063 what is the exact location of the file? It's not possible to tell from your question.

Answer (score 0):

Problem SOLVED. Thanks for your input.
Apparently the solution was tricky: the command I used was:
c:\elte\esti\beadando\javac -d c:\elte\esti\beadando\elte\esti\beadando NimJatek.java

And then

c:\elte\esti\beadando\javac -cp . NimMain.java

DONE!! It worked.
In words: if you have a package, and you need to use dos command prompt to compile, then:
- from the ROOT directory use the javac -d PACKAGEPATH FILENAME_A.java and then
from the same root directory the javac -cp . FILENAME_B.java
This is given the FILE_B uses FILE_A.